# Track expense memos and payees in GnuCash?

Tags: gnucash, expense-tracking

I'm using GnuCash to track a simple budget, importing QIF files.  Most entries in the QIF file have both a *payee* and a *memo*, however GnuCash seems to ignore the memo if the payee is specified.  This often makes it difficult to assign a payment to the account if I don't recognize the payee, or in the situation that payments are made to the same payee for multiple services or reasons.  Is there a way to track both the payee and memo, or at least prefer the memo over the salary?

Comment: I've noticed OFX files seem to do what I want.  Maybe I should transform to OFX instead of QIF...

Answer (score 1):

The consensus seems to be that upgrading to OFX is better vs. QIF because it uses a different transaction importer in GnuCash.  Not sure if that will address the specific memo/payee issue.

Comment: I think it does, I just need to write a CSV to OFX converter.

Answer (score 1):

If you press the Split button, you will see your memos on the transaction detail line for the account you imported (as opposed to your category account). So they are imported.

Sorry for waking this years old post but I got here researching the same issue and found the answer myself.